# Codeblocks 16.01 curly brackets indentation not working properly

Tags: codeblocks

When I type

```
if(){}
```

and press "enter" between the curly brackets, it should be like this

```
if()
{

}
```

but it appears like this

```
if(){

}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Why do you believe that it "should be like this"?

Comment: Sorry, but that is how it should be, I would even add an extra  space before the opening curly brace

Comment: @SamVarshavchik it "should be like this" because it is easier for me to see where the curly brackets begin and end